# VBA Evaluate function failing on simple test

Tags: excel, vba, formulas, evaluate

I'm trying to use Evaluate() to run an if statement in my code and store the result in an array, but every time I tried it returned a #VALUE! error. I thought this may have been because I was incorrectly using variables, so I gave it a simpler test:

```
arr(i, 9) = Evaluate("IF(1 > 2, 'yes', 'no')")
```

However, this still failed and returned a #VALUE! error.

Any help?

Comment: it needs `"` instead of `'` - `Evaluate("IF(1 > 2, ""yes"", ""no"")")`. You can notice the error if you try the expression in Excel formula